# How can I pass a sum to the next iteration of a list using map, in Scala?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, iteration

I have the following classes:

```
class Task(val Time: Int)
```

and

```
class TaskSchedule(val Start: Int, val: End: Int)
```

My goal is to create a list of TaskSchedule that sums the time iteratively from a list of tasks.

So, for example, if the first element of the Task list had a time 100, the first element of the generated TaskSchedule list would have a start 0 and end 100. If the following Task has a time of 200, the corresponding taskSchedule would have a start of 100 (result of the sum of the previous one) and an end of 300.

I was trying to do this with a map, but I have no idea how I can get the previous sum, or how to pass a sum to the next iteration.

```
tasks.map(t => {
    new TaskSchedule(
    //need previous sum or 0 if first,
    )
})
```

Is this possible with map? Or will I have to change my approach to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple solution**

Start with an empty list of `TaskSchedule` and a delta of 0. At every step, create a `TaskSchedule` using from `delta` to `delta` + time. Return the modified list tupled with the new `delta` to which we added the current time, so the next step accounts for it.

A few side notes, class params do not need to be uppercase in Scala, and you could use a `case class` there.

```
  case class Task(time: Int)

  case class TaskSchedule(start: Int, end: Int)

  def interleave(tasks: List[Task]): List[TaskSchedule] = {
    val (schedules, _) = tasks.foldLeft(List.empty[TaskSchedule] -> 0) { case ((list, delta), task) =>
      (TaskSchedule(delta, delta + task.time) :: list) -> (delta + task.time)
    }
    schedules.reverse
  }

   val result = interleave(List(Task(100), Task(200)))

   Console.println(result)
   // List(TaskSchedule(0,100), TaskSchedule(100,300))
```

To avoid reversing, you could use append instead.

```
  def interleave(tasks: List[Task]): List[TaskSchedule] = {
    val (schedules, _) = tasks.foldLeft(List.empty[TaskSchedule] -> 0) { case ((list, delta), task) =>
          (list :+ TaskSchedule(delta, delta + task.time)) -> (delta + task.time)
    }
    schedules
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Seq#scanLeft(...)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.0/scala/collection/Seq.html#scanLeft[B,That](z:B)(op:(B,A)=%3EB)(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[Repr,B,That]):That) operation does the closest to what you need:

```
tasks.
  scanLeft(new TaskSchedule(0, 0)) {
    case (lastSched: TaskSchedule, task: Task) => new TaskSchedule(lastSched.End, lastSched.End + task.Time)
  }.
  tail
```

Here's an alternative implementation where you do not have to first create a `new TaskSchedule(0, 0)`:

```
tasks.tail.scanLeft(new TaskSchedule(0, tasks.head.Time)) {
  case (lastSched: TaskSchedule, task: Task) => new TaskSchedule(lastSched.End, lastSched.End + task.Time)
}
```

I'll let you decide for yourself which is cleaner (I'm having a hard time deciding myself, though the second implementation creates one fewer object).

If you make `Task` and `TaskSchedule` case classes, you can make things a bit cleaner:

```
case class Task(time: Int)
case class TaskSchedule(start: Int, end: Int)

tasks: Seq[Task] = ...
tasks.tail.scanLeft(TaskSchedule(0, tasks.head.time)) {
  case (TaskSchedule(_, lastEnd), Task(time)) => TaskSchedule(lastEnd, lastEnd + time)
}
```

Incidentally, it is Scala convention to name variables in lower case (i.e., `time` instead of `Time`, `start` instead of `Start`, `end` instead of `End`).